# Chinese words make newest Eclipse's (2020-06) block comment indent display issue

Tags: eclipse

As screen shot illustrated, when Chinese word is the first word (blank is not count) after asterisk, the indent (5 blanks before asterisk, red block) font become smaller! But when it is not the first word (I add a dot before 中), the indent font (green block) become normal!

This did not happen in older Eclipse in my experience.

[image]

**Update**

I will find the way to report this to Eclipse community. I just want to know if there is anyone encounter this, too? And maybe something in preference which I can set to get around this?

Comment: It sounds like an Eclipse bug.  But this is not the place to report Eclipse bugs.

Comment: On Windows? If yes, this might also be a font issue (maybe related to [this new feature](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.16/platform.php#eclipse-win-ligatures-support)). In _Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts_, does changing the _Basic > Text Font_ help? @StephenC

Comment: My font is Consolas, charset is Western Europe and YES, it's on Win10. I check these settings before and it is the same as what I was used in older Eclipse.

YES, some fonts don't have this issue, including some Chinese fonts and "System", "Termical", "LG Display", and so on. But Consolas didn't have this issue in older Eclipse!

Comment: The issue may have become visible now due to the improved font support. The ligatures support requires that the spacing between characters is made as it is defined for each individual character or combination of characters in the font. If characters are missing, they are taken from other fonts. Therefore, it is better to use a font that contains all the required characters (the Consolas font that I have in my Windows 10 does not contain 中).